# View property not working in Google Dashboard

Tags: javascript, c#, google-api, google-visualization

Graph Code (Generated via C#)

```
 function drawDashboard() {
     var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
         ['Group', 'Month', 'Count'],
         ['A', 1, 9],
         ['B', 1, 1],
         ['C', 1, 7],
         ['A', 2, 25],
         ['B', 2, 1],
         ['C', 2, 3]
     ]);
     var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard_div'));
     var slider = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
         'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
         'containerId': 'filter_div',
         'options': {
             'filterColumnLabel': 'Month',
             'ui': {
                 'labelStacking': 'vertical',
                 'allowTyping': false,
                 'allowMultiple': false,
                 'allowNone': false
             }
         }
     });
     var ColumnChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
         'chartType': 'ColumnChart',
         'containerId': 'chart_div',
         'options': {
             'legend': 'right',

// Relevant bit start //
                 'view': {
                     'columns': [0,2]
                 },

// Relevant bit END //

             width: '100%',
             height: '250',
             vAxis: {
                 minValue: 0
             }
         }
     });

// Rest of the code which executes comes after this

 }
```

In my `option` property I've set `view` to use only *Group* and *Count*

```
 'view': {
          'columns': [0,2]
          },
```

0 = first value in array i.e Group 
2 = third value in array i.e Count 
in this

```
['Group', 'Month', 'Count']
```

But in my graph it is counting month as a value too. I just want to use Month as a filter. I do not want to show month as a value in the graph.

I don't want the blue column there. Only red should be there.

[image]

[Google Control Doc Reference here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`view` should be defined at the same level and separate from `options`

*not* within / as part of `options`

as such...

```
var ColumnChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
  'chartType': 'ColumnChart',
  'containerId': 'chart_div',
  'options': {
    'legend': 'right',
    'width': '100%',
    'height': 250,
    'vAxis': {
      'minValue': 0
    }
  },
  'view': {
    'columns': [0,2]
  }
});
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  'callback': function () {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Group', 'Month', 'Count'],
      ['A', 1, 9],
      ['B', 1, 1],
      ['C', 1, 7],
      ['A', 2, 25],
      ['B', 2, 1],
      ['C', 2, 3]
    ]);
    var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard_div'));
    var slider = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
      'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
      'containerId': 'filter_div',
      'options': {
        'filterColumnLabel': 'Month',
        'ui': {
          'labelStacking': 'vertical',
          'allowTyping': false,
          'allowMultiple': false,
          'allowNone': false
        }
      }
    });
    var ColumnChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
      'chartType': 'ColumnChart',
      'containerId': 'chart_div',
      'options': {
        'legend': 'right',
        'width': '100%',
        'height': 250,
        'vAxis': {
          'minValue': 0
        }
      },
      'view': {
        'columns': [0,2]
      }
    });
    dashboard.bind(slider, ColumnChart);
    dashboard.draw(data);
  },
  'packages': ['corechart', 'controls']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="filter_div"></div>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks ! it worked. Now another problem is coming as 'Should be an integer in the range [0-1].' I guess that entirely a new question.

Comment: sounds like it, when does the error occur? nothing thrown in the above answer. let me know if you add another question...